# How to reference cells by name in Libreoffice 4.2

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In the Libreoffice version that came with Ubuntu 12.04, I could select a column, [name it](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Naming_Cells), and then construct a formula that referenced this name.

e.g. Say I had two columns `A=Price` and `B=Quantity`. If I wanted to make `C=Price*Quantity` you could set it to a formula like:

```
=A1*B1
```

However, with named columns, you could also do:

```
=PRICE*QUANTITY
```

Obviously, this makes the formula much more readable, albeit it implicitly refers to the same row as the formula.

However, when I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, which uses Libreoffice 4.2, I found all my formulas that use this notation are broken and now show "#REF!". Yet under the "Manage names" option, I still see all my custom column/name mappings.

Was this incredibly useful feature removed or is something just misconfigured? How do I fix my formulas so that they still use names?

Comment: Does it work if you create it fresh (just a problem with legacy files)?